# What does it mean when Xcode returns (lldb) after scanf input?

Tags: xcode, scanf

I'm working through the book "C Programming Absolute Beginner's Guide to learn a little more about C so I can better understand what I need to do for an Arduino project. I'm using Xcode 12.4 on a Big Sur iMac because CodeBlocks, the IDE used in the book's examples, doesn't work on this computer.

In the chapter that covers scanf() when I run the sample program, Xcode returns (lldb) after my first input. Here's my simplified program that exhibits that return:

```
//
//  main.c
//  Chapter8ex1a
//
//  Created by Kellidad on 3/25/21.
//
/*  This program asks the user for some basic data and prints it on the screen to show 
    what was entered */

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    // setup the variables that scanf will fill
    
    char firstInitial;
    char lastInitial;
    
    printf("What letter does your first name begin with?\n");
    scanf(" %c, &firstInitial");
    
    printf("What letter does your last name begin with?\n");
    scanf(" %c, &lastInitial");
    
    printf("\nYour initials are %c.%c.", firstInitial, lastInitial);

    return 0;

    }
```

And here's what is displayed in the console:

```
What letter does your first name begin with?
L [followed by <Return>]
(lldb)
```

In addition, Xcode displays "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" at the first scanf() line.

Matt suggested it's a prompt waiting for something else, but if I repeat and enter another character I get this:

```
What letter does your first name begin with? 
L <Enter> 
(lldb) H <Enter> 
error: 'H' is not a valid command. 
(lldb)
```

Unfortunately, what I've found about (lldb) is meaningless to me. Can I make scanf() work in this example using Xcode or is there a better way for a beginner to accept characters from the keyboard?

Thanks!

Comment: If I enter anything else it reports an error, as follows:
What letter does your first name begin with?
L <Enter>
(lldb) H <Enter>
error: 'H' is not a valid command.
(lldb) 

Also, Xcode displays "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" after the first scanf() line.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the position of the " " in the scanf() - the function should read scanf(" %c", &firstInitial); not scanf(" %c, &firstInitial");